# .py files not opening since One drive is synced

Tags: pycharm, onedrive

I am not able to Open pycharm and .py files since Onedrive is synced with all of my desktop folders. I tried to stop the sync but it starts syncing automatically again. Can anyone help me, the logo of pycharm is also missing from all the .py files and from the pycharm itself

Comment: Don't store source code under OneDrive - use `git` or other VCS. It is also not recommended to use IDE with file sync software like OneDrive - they might start fighting with each other over file revisions to save. If you would like to open `py` files with PyCharm - create the corresponding file association between `py` file type and IDE in Windows settings. Not sure what do you mean by the missing PyCharm logo from PyCharm itself. Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Also OneDrive has some locking mechanism which are not 100% transparent to the program. It is possible that one configuration file is opened twice. I agree with Pavel (OTOH I'm less convinced to the reasoning, in fact PyCharm allow you to remote execute files, so why not just a cloud file (so a intermediate between local and remote). If you want, you can file a bug to PyCharm. It may help to correct corner cases (and so to make PyCharm more robust)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The standard way of executing a python script on Windows is calling the python interpreter with the script name as parameter on the (DOS) command line. It is necessary though that the path to python.exe is included in your Path system variable.

python myprogram.py